# C# TextWriter inserting line break every 1024 characters

Tags: c#, text

I'm using the textwriter to write data to a text file but if the line exceeds 1024 characters a line break is inserted and this is a problem for me. Any suggestions on how to work round this or increase the character limit?

```
textWriter.WriteLine(strOutput);
```

Many thanks

Comment: Could you show where strOutput is coming from? Does it come from a buffer? If so, how is that buffer filled, and how big is it?

Comment: are you viewing the textfile with notepad??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a sample app that writes and read a 1025 character string.  The size never changes.  Although if I opened it with notepad.exe (Windows) I can see the extra character in the second line.  These seems like a notepad limitation.  Here is my sample code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter("lineLimit.txt")) {
            String s=String.Empty;
            for(int i=0;i<1025;i++){
                s+= i.ToString().Substring(0,1);
            }
            streamWriter.Write(s);
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        using (TextReader streamReader = new StreamReader("lineLimit.txt"))
        {
            String s = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            streamReader.Close();
            Console.Out.Write(s.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yup, this could well be it - in other words, the problem didn't exist in the first place :)

Comment: It was a notepad limitation, notepad2 shows it perfectly, thanks for all your time. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Use Write, not WriteLine

Answer (score 5):

Well you're using [`TextWriter.WriteLine(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ack4zyt.aspx) which appends `\r\n` after `strOutput`. As the docs say:

> Writes a string *followed by a line terminator* to the text stream.

(Emphasis mine.) That has nothing to do with 1024 characters though - my guess is that that's how you're reading it in (e.g. with a buffer of 1024 characters).

To avoid the extra line break, just use

```
textWriter.Write(strOutput);
```

EDIT: You say in the comment that you need a line break after "the full line has been written out" - but it sounds like `strOutput` isn't always the same line.

I suspect the easiest way of accomplishing what you want is to separate the "copying" side out from the "line break" side. Use `Write` for all the text you want to copy, and then just call

```
textWriter.WriteLine();
```

when you want a line break. If this doesn't help, I think we're going to need more context - please provide a code sample of exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be exactly the issue. There's certainly nothing intrinsic to the TextWriter/StreamWriter class that imposes a 1024 (or any) limit.

Comment: Thank Jon, I need the line break inserting after the full line has been written using .Write(strOutput); what would be the best way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Thanks Jon, darn notepad limitation! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to add the line breaks at the end of your output just append them.

```
textWriter.Write(strOutput +"\r\n");
```